# A thread that handles WinForm is blocks when i start some task in parallel

Tags: c#, winforms, parallel.foreach

everybody!
So i have an form, which has an BackgroundWorker and a TextBox. When i click btn then worker.RunWorkerAsync() is called, and in event DoWork i actualy start some nested Parallel.ForEach() loops. Theese loops do some calculations which results to be textbox value changed, so in theese loops i call worker.ReportProgress(0, textBoxValue) that fires event progressChanged(sender,ProgressChangedEventArgs) and when i handle this event i simply change textBox value on which was passed in event args. So my issue is that whole form sometimes active and textbox value updates, some times it is not.Here is my code look like.

```
public class Form{
 BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
 TextBox textBox = new TextBox();
 RichTextBox rb = new RixhTextBox();
 public Form(){
   worker.DoWork += DoWork;
   worker.ProgressChanged += ProgressChanged;
   worker.RunWorkerCompleted += WorkerCompleted;
   worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
   worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

   worker.runWorkerAsync();
 }
 private void DoWork(object sender,DoWorkEventArgs e){
  Parallel.ForEach(list,item =>{
   //some work
   Parallel.ForEach(list2,item2=>{
    //some work
    worker.ReportProgress(0,param);
   }
  }

  private void ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e){
   //update richtextbox
   //update textbox
  }
 }
}
```

pls give me some advise how to debug this situtation?
Edited: richtextbox updates correctly but from not active

Comment: You can get the main thread to burn 100% core, and become unresponsive, by calling ReportProgress() too often and/or incrementally add a large amount of text to the TextBox.  Considerably beyond what the user's eyes can possibly observe, keep the UI practical and usable and this problem automatically disappears.

Comment: I find that it can be better to update a progress-variable (using interlocked to be safe), and have a timer that polls this variable and updates a progress bar. That way it does not matter how often the progress is updated.

Comment: @HansPassant "keep the UI practical and usable" is too abstract phrase, may you give me something concrete? how can i update ui progress using parallel working?

Comment: @JonasH i'll try to add timer, thanks

Comment: i forgot to mention that also i have a richtextbox which lines are updated in progressChanged and it  updates correctly but form is not active

Comment: What "keep the UI practical and usable" means is that if you update the UI so fast that users can't catch up with their eyes, the UI update is meaningless